# How to displaying an specific attributes with a many to many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have a two way many-to-many assoication between 3 models: work.rb, category.rb, categorywork.rb

Within the `work#index` using `<%= work.categories %>` renders some wonky looking html markup

[image: wonky]

```
<% @works.each do |work| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= work.name %></td>
    <td><%= work.subtitle %></td>
    <td><%= work.categories %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', work %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_work_path(work) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', work, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to target speific attributes of the association like "name".

Unfortunately when using `<%= work.categories.name %>` it gets weirder with:
[image: wonkier]

How do i target just the name or just the description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<%= work.categories.pluck(:name) %>
```